# How to connect Two Dark Mode buttons on the same Page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been using two dark mode buttons on my Page. One at menu bar and the other on the Footer.

However, the problem is that whenver I switch to dark mode from any one button the other button doesn't toggles itself.

Say, if I switch the night Mode from Menu bar, then the footer button will keep showing that the Day Mode is enabled.

This is my [Website Test Page.](https://freeairdrop.io/airdrop/bannertest2.html)

Kindly help in solving my problem with code as well.

Thanks

Code for button on Menu Bar

```
    <label class="switch" style="padding: 23px 0;">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="theme-switcher">
        <div>
            <span></span>
        </div>
```

Code for button on Footer

```
    <label class="switcher">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="theme-switcher-2">
    <div>
    <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left arrow"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    </div>
    </label>
```

The js for both the buttons

```
    var tSwitcher = document.getElementsByClassName('theme-switcher');
    let element = document.body;

    let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
    if (onpageLoad != null && onpageLoad == 'dark-mode') {
            for(let i = 0; i<tSwitcher.length; i++){
                    tSwitcher[i].checked = true;    
        }

    }

    if(onpageLoad) element.classList.add(onpageLoad);

    function themeToggle() {
        if (event.target.checked) {
          localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
          element.classList.add('dark-mode');
        } else {
          localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
          element.classList.remove('dark-mode');
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get both of checkboxes it's better to use `querySelectorAll`:

`querySelectorAll('[class^=theme-switcher]')`

LocalStorage doesn't work in snippet but you can check it on your staging site

```js
var tSwitcher = document.querySelectorAll('[class^=theme-switcher]');
let element = document.body;
let onpageLoad = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "";
if (onpageLoad != null && onpageLoad == 'dark-mode') {
      for(let i = 0; i<tSwitcher.length; i++){
          tSwitcher[i].checked = true;    
      }

}

if(onpageLoad) element.classList.add(onpageLoad);

function themeToggle() {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
      tSwitcher.forEach(function(el){ 
          element.classList.add('dark-mode');
          el.checked = true;
      })
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
      tSwitcher.forEach(function(el){ 
          element.classList.remove('dark-mode');
          el.checked = false;
       })
    }
  }
```

```html
<label class="switch" style="padding: 23px 0;">
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="theme-switcher">
        <div>
            <span></span>
        </div>

    <label class="switcher">
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="theme-switcher-2">
    <div>
    <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-arrow-left arrow"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-moon"></i>
    </div>
    </label>
```

Comment: What did you meant when you said "LocalStorage doesn't work in snippet"? Will this affect my website? @Banzay

Comment: either you can "modernize" js by replacing `tSwitcher.forEach(function(el){` with `[...tSwitcher]((el)=>{`

Comment: "LocalStorage doesn't work in snippet" - try to run snippet - it will throw an error of localStorage use - it's just SO security restriction

Comment: No, no, I meant if it has any disadvantage? @Banzay

Comment: No issues should be in live site

Comment: Okay.. Thanks a lot again, sir. Good Day :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var tSwitcher = document.getElementsByClassName('theme-switcher')[0];
var t2 = document.getElementsByClassName('theme-switcher-2')[0];
        
 function themeToggle() {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    tSwitcher.checked = true; 
    t2.checked = true
    localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-mode');
    element.classList.add('dark-mode');
  } else {
     tSwitcher.checked = false; 
     t2.checked = false
     localStorage.setItem('theme', '');
     element.classList.remove('dark-mode');
  }
}
```

```html
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="theme-switcher">
 <input type="checkbox" onclick="themeToggle()" class="theme-switcher-2">
```

whenever `themeToggle` is called, change the `checked` attribute of both the inputs.

Comment: It is not working when the Page is refreshed @priyanshu sinha

Comment: Please fix the issue @priyanshu sinha

Comment: for that, you'll have to add the same logic in `onpageLoad` event as well where you have the `tSwitcher[i].checked = true;` logic @neeraj

Comment: Can you please explain by code? Actually I am not a developer and just trying to add. @priyanshu sinha

Comment: `if (onpageLoad != null && onpageLoad == 'dark-mode') {
            for(let i = 0; i<tSwitcher.length; i++){
                    tSwitcher[i].checked = true; t2.checked = true    
        }

    }`